# Jscrollpane , Textfield and Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jtextfield, jscrollpane

Hello the problem I have is I want to display a big picture in the jscrollpane with the jlabel icon,
And I also want to add on the jscrollpane the textfield what i'm looking for is an interaction between the textfield and the jscrollpane with the image displayed with the jlabel on jscrollpane

```
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
    textField2 = new java.awt.TextField();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setAutoscrolls(false);
    jTextArea1.setEnabled(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1500, 1500));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(2000, 2000));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton1);
    jButton1.setBounds(90, 190, 73, 23);

    textField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    getContentPane().add(textField1);
    textField1.setBounds(50, 340, 1820, 70);

    textField2.setEditable(false);
    textField2.setEnabled(false);
    textField2.setVisible(false);
    getContentPane().add(textField2);
    textField2.setBounds(60, 150, 650, 20);

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("D:\\picture.jpg")); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jLabel1);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2);
    jScrollPane2.setBounds(0, 220, 1890, 600);

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton2);
    jButton2.setBounds(220, 190, 73, 23);

    pack();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want multiple things inside a scroll pane, add them to a `JPanel` and make that `JPanel` be the scrollpane`s ViewPortView.

Comment: hi bro thank you for your reply but doesnt work me i have always the same problem thak you a lot